# Monitoring training and validation metrics in the same TensorBoard graph with a multi-batched validation dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I'm currently trying to monitor my `TensorFlow` model with `tf.Summaries`, `tf.FileWriter` and `TensorBoard`.

I succeeded in plotting training metrics, as well as in plotting validation (and/or testing) metrics. However, my problem is that I did not succeed in plotting both dataset metrics together in the same graph: as my validation dataset is too large, I have to batch it and I can not settle for standard solutions that currently work for MNIST and other canonical datasets (see *e.g.* [this Github example code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cf7c008ab150ac8e5edb3ed053d38b2919699796/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py#L142) of Mnist with summaries, or some Stackeroverflow threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146614/tensorboard-plot-training-and-validation-losses-on-the-same-graph), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471563/logging-training-and-validation-loss-in-tensorboard) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146428/show-training-and-validation-accuracy-in-tensorflow-using-same-graph)).

As my validation dataset is multi-batched, I'm forced to use value and update ops as described *e.g.* by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739639/add-a-summary-of-accuracy-of-the-whole-train-test-dataset-in-tensorflow/47098910#47098910) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788785/how-to-average-summaries-over-multiple-batches/47421953#47421953).

Here is a minimal working example corresponding to what I am trying to do:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets import mnist

dataset = mnist.read_data_sets("data", one_hot=True, reshape=False, validation_size=0)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='X', shape=[None, 28, 28, 1])              
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='Y', shape=[None, 10])                     

# Conv layer                                                             
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 1, 8]), name="weights_c1", trainable=True)                                                                           
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([8])/10, name="biases_c1", trainable=True)            
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X, w1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", name="conv1")                                                                                  
conv_bias1 = tf.add(conv1, b1, name="convbias1")                               
relu1 = tf.nn.relu(conv_bias1, name="relu1")

# Max pooling layer                                                      
pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")

# Fully-connected layer                                                        
reshaped = tf.reshape(pool1, [-1, 14 * 14 * 8])                                 
wfc = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([14 * 14 * 8, 500]),                     
                  name="weights_fc", trainable=True)                           
bfc = tf.Variable(tf.ones([500])/10, name="biases_fc", trainable=True)        
fc = tf.add(tf.matmul(reshaped, wfc), bfc, name="raw_fc")                      
relu_fc = tf.nn.relu(fc, name="relu_fc")    

# Output layer                                                                 
wo = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([500, 10]), name="weights_output", trainable=True)                                                                         
bo = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10])/10, name="biases_output", trainable=True)       
logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(relu_fc, wo), bo, name="logits")                 
Y_raw_predict = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="y_pred_raw")                       
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y)
# Optimization
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)                                           
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)                        
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y_raw_predict, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))

# Accuracy computing (definition of a summary for training,
# and value/update ops for batched testing)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))             
acc_sum = tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)                              
mean_acc_value, mean_acc_update = tf.metrics.mean(accuracy, name="mean_accuracy_op")                                                                             
tf.summary.scalar("mean_accuracy", mean_acc_value, collections = ["test"])

# tf.Summary and tf.FileWriter settings
train_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()                                         
test_summary = tf.summary.merge_all("test")                               
graph_path = "./logs/mnist/graph/mnist1"                                      
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join(graph_path, "training"))     
test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join(graph_path, "testing"))       

# tf.Session opening and graph filling                                                            
with tf.Session() as sess:                                                                                                                        
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())                                
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer()) # for value/update ops
    for step in range(301):                                                                                                                                     
        xbatch, ybatch = dataset.train.next_batch(100)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: xbatch, Y:ybatch})
        # Monitor training each 10 steps
        if step % 10 == 0:
            s, l, acc, accsum = sess.run([train_summary, loss, accuracy, acc_sum],
                                         feed_dict={X: xbatch, Y: ybatch})                                                                            
            train_writer.add_summary(s, step)                                  
            print("step: {}, loss={:5.4f}, acc={:0.3f}".format(step, l, acc))
        # Monitor testing data each 100 steps
        if step % 100 == 0:
            # Consider 10000 testing images by batch of 100 images
            for test_step in range(101):
                xtest, ytest = dataset.test.next_batch(100)                      
                sess.run([mean_acc_update], feed_dict={X: xtest, Y: ytest})                                                                               
            tacc, testsum = sess.run([mean_acc_value, test_summary])                                                                          
            test_writer.add_summary(testsum, step)                              
            print("Validation OK: acc={:0.3f}".format(tacc))
```

I get the following results on TensorBoard (two different graphs, when I want two curves on the same graph):
[TensorBoard result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTiPY.png)
(expected result as [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYuka.png), for instance)

Here comes the question: how to combine training and validation metrics in the same graph, when validation dataset has to be splitted into batches?

Thank you all!